# Use and purpose for Optional PaletteIntention members in MaterialUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can't seem to find in any of the Material-UI documentation where the "light", "dark" and "contrastText" properties of a PaletteIntention are applied or what they are used for?  I know I can access them with hooks or HOC directly, but I am wondering if those variants are used in any of the built-in components automatically? This is probably obvious, so thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the manual? https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/ there is a pretty good explanation there. If something isn't clear let us know.

Comment: Yes, I have spent quite a bit of time going through the manual.  Like I said I must be missing something obvious, but while I see where palette.primary.light, for example, is introduced and how to override it or how it is calculated from main if omitted, but I don't see anything that explains its use or why it exists. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those theme values are used in MUI components.

---

The keyword `PaletteIntention` has only appeared in the document [theme/palette/customization](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#customization) for explanation.

[image]

What it wants to say is that we can customize the theme default settings.

---

If we take a close look at the `built-in` component source like the most common one `Button`

- Refer: the source of [MUI Button](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js)

You can find that the default styles are using the theme

```
export const styles = (theme) => ({
  /* Styles applied to the root element. */
  root: {
    ...theme.typography.button,
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    minWidth: 64,
    padding: '6px 16px',
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    color: theme.palette.text.primary,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['background-color', 'box-shadow', 'border'], {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.short,
    }),
```

Which is quite common. I mean, why not they use the style solution inside their own package?

The document may not list all the default style one component is using, still, we can see it inside the source, and we can always customize them via the CSS API document, or override them using the MUI `nesting selector` or other style solution provided by MUI with theme.

---

Refer: document of

- [MUI style solutions](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/)
- [MUI theming](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/)
- [customizing-components](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#customizing-components)
- [advanced/#theming](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#theming)

Comment: Searching through the source code I have found some sparing use of the dark and contrastText variants which answers my question.  Thanks for pointing me to the source.